# Logical processor does not appear in omnetpp application

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, parallel-processing, omnet++

I need to run in omnetpp application parallelly, I made the configuration of.ini file as follow

```
parallel-simulation = true
parsim-communications-class = cMPICommunications
parsim-synchronization-class = cNullMessageProtocol
```

the program build completed successfully, but when initialization the console view the following

> cMPICommunications: started as process 0 out of 1.
> WARNING: MPI thinks this process is the only one in the session (did you use mpirun to start this program?)
> Loading NED files from ..: 4
> Loading NED files from ../../src: 8
> Loading NED files from ../../../inet/examples: 151
> Loading NED files from ../../../inet/src: 492
> Loading NED files from ../../../inet/tutorials: 4
> Preparing for running configuration General, run #6...
> Scenario: $0=500, $repetition=0
> Assigned runID=General-6-20220301-23:26:45-19607
> Setting up network `Fog'...
> <!> Error in module (cModule) Fog (id=1) during network setup: wrong partitioning: value 1 too large for 'Fog.Broker' (total partitions=1).
> End.

I think that there are some configuration i missed, probably the configuration that pass the number of LPs to the omnetpp

in omnetpp manual they state that passing number of LPs must done as follow

```
./cqn -p0,3 &
./cqn -p1,3 &
./cqn -p2,3 &
```

but I don't know where to add these lines exactly

Comment: How did you start your simulation? Could you show a command that you used?

Comment: I start the simulation using  Run -> Run as -> omnetpp simulation

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your project's name is `foo` and the `Target type` is equal to `Executable` (in `Project` | `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | `Options` | `Target`). After compilation an executable file called `foo` (in Windows: `foo.exe`) is created.
Open the console (in Windows: mingwenv) and go to the directory where your project is located, for example:

```
cd somefolder/foo
```

Then type the command you need.